# require is not defined suddenly happening on 3rd party libraries

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Just in the last few days two separate websites I have been managing are producing this error when one of the third party libraries tries to execute a "require"

For example, we use Masonry.js (https://masonry.desandro.com/) and it's failing here:

```
module.exports = e(t, require("jquery"))
```

Or another example is imagesloaded.js:

```
module.exports = e(t, require("ev-emitter"))
```

Nothing has changed in our code base for months so I'm not sure how this can suddenly be happening. I'm happy to provide any further details if someone has a clue what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I found the problem. It had to do with a library called MarkerWithLabel.js which is a Google Maps addon.

https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js

I downgraded it to another source and it was fine